# R function for a stacked barplot in a size range

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to create a barplot for a size range. I present a dummy dataset (data)

```
Size1   Size2    A     B      C
0        5     0.3    0.5   0.2
5       10     0.1    0.2   0.7
10      20     0.5    0.2   0.3
20      50     0.2    0.4   0.4
50      100    0.7    0.1   0.2
```

I can create a plot if there was just one "Size". For example if there was only "Size2" I'd do something like

```
library(reshape2)
data1 <- melt(data, id.var="Size2")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data1, aes(x = Size2, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

With this I get 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTNtE.jpg

However, I want a plot for A, B, C within each size range. So with Size on the x-axis and percent of A, B, and C on the y-axis, how can I proceed further. I want the lines of the barplot to be connected i.e no gaps between bars in the x-axis.

Comment: Use `data$Size = paste(data$Size1, data$Size2, sep = "-")`, to create a single Size column indicating the range (drop the other size columns when you melt). To make the bars connect, set `width = 1` in `geom_bar`

Comment: @Gregor thank you. it works for this data. But for my data i need to change my size to a log scale and make a bar for each size range. Is there a way to do it without the ` sep = "-" ` ?

Comment: `geom_bar` works well with categorical x-axes. If you want to use a continuous x-axis, I'd recommend using `geom_rect`. But in that case you'll need to calculate the percentages yourself, I think.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to it is:

```
size1 <- c(0,5,10,20,50)
size2 <- c(5,10,20,50,100)
A = c(0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7)
B <- c(0.5,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.1)
C <- c(0.2, 0.7,0.3,0.4,0.2)

data <- data.frame(Size1=factor(size1),   # this removes gaps between bars in x axis)
                 Size2=factor(size2),
                 A=A,
                 B=B,
                 C=C)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
data1 <- melt(data[,c("Size1","A","B","C")], id.var="Size1")
data2 <- melt(data[,c("Size2","A","B","C")], id.var="Size2")

library(ggplot2)
g1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = Size1, y = value, fill = variable,)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE)
g2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x = Size2, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

g1 <- ggplotGrob(g1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(g2)
g <- cbind(g1, g2)
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Two barplots look the same because the value of A, B and C are the same for size1 and size2.

Comment: I think OP wants a single bar plot where position of the bars on the x-axis goes from `size1` to `size2` (that is, a `geom_rect` plot). Not two different bar plots.

Comment: @Tianyu Zhang thank you but as Gregor rightly points out that what I'm looking for is a single bar plot